# What is the alternative to Comparator<T> when using composition over inheritance?

Tags: java, sorting, inheritance, collections, composition

While refactoring a Java project to use composition and no inheritance, I have remaining a problem where polymorphic sorting of Collections was performed.

Inheritance example:

```
public class AClass
{
    private List<OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances> unsortedList;

    public List<OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances> getSortedList()
    {
        List<OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances> sortedList = new ArrayList(this.unsortedList);
        Collections.sort(sortedList, SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances.orderComparator);

        return sortedList;
    }
}
```

Now, after refactoring; classes `OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` no longer inherit from abstract `SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` but `Collections.sort()` expects mutually comparable instances.

What is the best way to refactor this?

#### Edit:

For completeness; I've added the Comparator implementation and further clarification of the problem.

```
public class SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances
{
    private int order;

    public static final Comparator<SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances> orderComparator = new Comparator<SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances>()
    {
        public int compare(SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances o1, SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances o2)
        {
            if ((o1 == null) && (o2 == null))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o1 == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o2 == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return (new Integer(o1.getOrder()).compareTo(new Integer(o2
                .getOrder())));
        }
    };


    public int getOrder()
    {
        return this.order;
    }


    public void setOrder(int order)
    {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

The crux of the issue is that after refactoring to composition, `OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` no longer `"is a"` `SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` and so the code is broken.

Many classes such as `OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` no longer have a common parent. So, the `Collections.sort()` can't be used across these classes with only a single implementation of `Comparator`.
Classes such as `OneClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` now instead have a `SuperClassOfManyThatRequireSortedInstances` member; a `"has a"` relationship.

Comment: What does `orderComparator` look like (signature)?

Comment: Do the minimum necessary for it to work. Extract an interface that exposes the methods you need and make all the classes that used to inherit from the supertype implement it.

Comment: Above comment from Zutty is the solution in a nutshell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume there are two classes, `Car` and `Train`. You could create an Interface like

```
public interface SpeedProvider {
    int getSpeed();
}
```

Then both `Car` and `Train` implement `SpeedProvider` Interface

```
public class Car implements SpeedProvider {
    int maxSpeed = 220;

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }
}

public class Train implements SpeedProvider {
    int maxSpeed = 300;

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

Last, you could implement a `Comparator` that compares two `SpeedProvider`

```
public class VehicleComparator implements Comparator<SpeedProvider> {
    @Override
    public int compare(SpeedProvider o1, SpeedProvider o2) {
        /* ... */
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this approach worked, thanks. I already had an interface for the member so I just used that.It just meant I had to implement accessor methods also which I had previously left out to reduce visually the length of chained getters, substituting with protected scoped members.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense. `Comparator<T>` is used in compositon. The alternative when using inheritance is `Comparable<T>`. Your question is back to front.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a contract by interface where by you have certain sort methods that return based on a particular set of fields (like the super classes used).  Then you can have one class that does the sort calculation and another set of classes that do the sorting based on different sets of fields/ compositions.

Then you can simply pass an instance of a Comparator that will do the sorting required and it will check for instanceof ... you can choose to throw an error or log and quietly return a default if a particular interface is not implemented.